# reconstruction of a skeletonized object

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

Using matlab, I tried to thin a square and a round object. Their skeletons are almost same and they shaped like an 'X'. So can I assume that, there is not a guarantee of reconstruct a thinned object? (and also I was expecting just a one pixel wide dot for skeleton of the round object, but I don't know maybe it was because of some noise)

Comment: What do you mean by reconstructing? There are better skeletonization algorithms out there, that produce results closer to the "centra of minimum balls" that you intuitively presume the skeleton should produce. Most skeletonization algorithms have trouble correctly getting to that solution because it is a non-trivial problem to recognize corners on the boundary of a binarized object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a reconstruction, you have to use the Median Axis and not the skeleton.

The median axis is a "kind" of skeleton that is composed of balls, each point of the skeleton being the center of a ball, and it guaranties that the overlap of all the balls will reconstruct the object.

The best papers in the domain were published by Borgefor, and so far the best algorithm is the one developed by Eric Remy and Edouard Thiel.